# Isometry of the Poincare Half Plane

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

$D_{(0,s)}(x,y)=(sx, sy)$. Is this an isometry of the Poincare Half Plane and if so, how can this be proved?

How would this change if $D_{(0,s)}(x,y)$ changes to $D_{(w,s)}(x,y)$?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by  "How would this change if $D_(0,s)(x,y)$ changes to $D_(w,s)(x,y)$?".

Answer (score 1):

The metric is $$g={dx^2+dy^2\over y^2}$$ if $D$ is you map $$D^*g={(ds.x)^2+(ds.y)^2\over (sy)^2}=g$$

Comment: where did the g come from?

Comment: $g$ is the Poincaré metric on the upper half plane. What is your definition of the distance ?

Comment: distance between two points on the Poincare half plane is some very long natural log that incorporates the x and y coordinates of both points.

Comment: This "very long " formula must be a cross ratio of $P,Q, P'Q'$, where $P,Q,P',Q'$ are cocyclic, and $P',Q'$ on the real line. The point is that this cross ratio is invariant by the action of $PSL(2,\bf R)$, and your transformation is the action of the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\sqrt s, {1\over \sqrt  s}$